# Make cube follow character five steps behind unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

At the moment I have a script which when you hit a cube, it follows the player...but when you stand still it overlaps you. What I want is to be able to set the position of the cube to five steps behind the player at all times...how would i do this?

```
GameObject.Find("Cube2").transform.position = Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
```

That is what I have tried so far, but that just makes the cube disappear?

the script in its entirety:

```
       static var target : Transform; //the enemy's target
    var moveSpeed = 3; //move speed
    var rotationSpeed = 3; //speed of turning    
    var Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    var Cube2 = GameObject.Find("Cube2").transform.position;

    var myTransform : Transform; //current transform data of this enemy

    function Awake()
    {
    //myTransform = transform; //cache transform data for easy access/preformance
    }

    function Start()
    {
    //target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1").transform; //target the player

    }    
    //var distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, Cube2.transform.position);
    //Debug.Log(distance);

    function Update () {



    Debug.Log(Player);

    //var distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, Cube2.transform.position);
    //var distance = Vector3.Distance(player_distance, cube_distance);

//    if (distance > 5)
   // {

    if (target == GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform)
    {
    //rotate to look at the player
    GameObject.Find("Cube2").transform.position = Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,
    Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);

    //move towards the player
    myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


    }
    //}


    }
```

Comment: You should probably keep track of the player and measure the distance from the player to the cube. When it becomes more than the target distance, then move the cube - setting the cubes position to `Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` will set it to an absolute position. I haven't written any unity scripts before but I can have a go at a solution if you would like

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, I don't know unity really (had a 5 minute play with it)

In honesty it looks like you've pretty much got it - not sure why you can't get it working:

This is what should work: (assuming the quarternion calls are correct) - this is using latest Unity reference from the site so it might be diff to what works for you (what version of Unity you on?)

```
// Params
var moveSpeed = 3; // Move speed
var rotationSpeed = 3; // Speed of turning    

// Find game objects
var Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
var Cube2 = GameObject.Find("Cube2");

function Update () 
{
    // Vector from cube pos to player pos (vector math: target - position = vector to target from pos)
    var dir = Player.transform.position - Cube2.transform.position;

    // If the distance is over 5 units
    if(dir.magnitude > 5.0f)
    {
        // Rotate towards player
        Cube2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Cube2.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Move forward at specified speed
        Cube2.transform.position += Cube2.transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

That should do it - if not let me know what happens (or if you get compilation errors) - like I said I don't really know Unity but I've had a look and I'm familiar with 3D/game programming